# How do I do this "CozaLozaWoza" code perfectly?

Tags: c

**Basically...**

Our teacher gave us homework to perform "CozaLozaWoza". [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCWcY.png)
(Picture from Chegg as reference)

I eventually managed to get it working (I guess?), but the problem was that my code was still printing unnecessary stuff on each lines, like printing ***Coza, Loza and Wozas*** in places where they shouldn't, can you guys tell me what did I do wrong? or did I missed something? Thanks.

Heres the code:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<conio.h>

main(){
    
    int _a,
        _b=110;
        
    for(_a=1;_a<=_b;_a+=1){
            
        if(_a%3==0){
            
            printf(" Coza");
        }
        
        if(_a%5==0){
            
            printf(" Loza");
        }
        
        if(_a%7==0){
            
            printf(" Woza");
        }
        
        if(_a%3==0 && _a%5==0){
                
            printf(" CozaLoza");
        }
        
        if(_a%3==0 && _a%7==0){
            
            printf(" CozaWoza");
        }
        
        if(_a%3!=0 && _a%5!=0 && _a%7!=0){
            
            printf(" %d", _a);
        }
        
        if(_a%11==0){
            
            printf("\n");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please type/paste in the problem description as text and not an image. Please also give the exact actual result vs expected result.

Comment: Just do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace its execution. It should be clear that `if(_a%3==0 && _a%5==0)` and `if(_a%3==0)` should be mutually exclusive - only one of those conditions should be executed for each iteration. At the moment your code evaluates both. You need to re-arrange the conditions and use `else if` instead of all `if` checks.

Comment: While everything defaults to type `int` when not specified, unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/). Remove `conio.h`.

Comment: Your problem statement and the answer shown in your image are technically inconsistent. Your problem statement does not provide for an encoding for multiples of 5 AND 7 (e.g. `"LozaWoza"`) absent also being a multiple of 3 -- but the answer given does. Something worth asking about. All other combinations for encoding are explicitly stated in the problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

- Alternatively, if you use a flag to note when a number is encoded as `CozaLozaWoza`, you can simplify things.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_BREAK_COUNT    11
#define UPPER_LIMIT         110

int main() {

    for (int num = 1; num <= UPPER_LIMIT; num += 1) {
        int encoded = 0;
        if (num % 3 == 0) {
            printf ("Coza");
            encoded = 1;
        }
        if (num % 5 == 0) {
            printf ("Loza");
            encoded = 1;
        }
        if (num % 7 == 0) {
            printf ("Woza");
            encoded = 1;
        }
        if (!encoded)
            printf ("%d", num);

        putchar (' ');      // space after each number
        if (num % LINE_BREAK_COUNT == 0)  // Line break
            putchar ('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- As pointed out in the comments, you don't need `conio.h` & `main()` should be declared to return `int`
- Use `#define`s in place of magic numbers for ease of maintenance.
- Avoid using variables prefixed with `_` in your code. Let them be succinct to the context they're used in.

Comment: Ill vote for your answer. Good job keeping track of the `encoded` state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code given below and it works perfectly fine.

There were several mistakes that you had done during coding and those are the reasons which lead you to a wrong output.

- You hadn't put else if condition.So thatsome number were went though
  the condition even after evaluated true in another condition.

As an example `15` is multiple of `3` and `5`.So as you have programmed it will pass the condition if(`_a%3==0 && _a%5==0`) and then print **CozaLoza** and after exiting that if block it will enter to other conditional statements because you have used just `if` instead of of `else if` or `nested if`.So when it enter if(`_a%3==0`) and if(`_a%5==0`)it will print the desired word again.

```
# include<stdio.h>


void main(){
    
    int _a;
    int _b;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",& _b);
    for(_a=1;_a<=_b;_a++){
        if(_a%3 == 0 && _a%5==0 && _a%7==0){
            
            printf(" CozaLozaWoza");
        }
        
        else if (_a%5==0 && _a%7==0){
            
            printf(" LozaWoza");
        }
        
        else if(_a%3==0 && _a%7==0){
            
            printf(" CozaWoza");
        }
        
        else if(_a%3==0 && _a%5==0){
                
            printf(" CozaLoza");
        }
        
        else if(_a%3==0){
            
            printf(" Coza");
        }
        
        else if(_a%5==0){
            
            printf(" Loza");
        }
        
        else if(_a%7==0){
            
            printf(" Woza");
        }
        else{
            printf(" %d", _a);
        }
        if(_a%11==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The main purpose of these kind of challenges is to see how the programmer is able to deal with code repetition. This might print the correct results, but you have massive code repetition all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @जलजनक (which is quite good), you can simply build a string based on the multiples of 3, 5, 7 and if the string is populated, output the string, otherwise output the digit. You can use a *ternary* to determine whether to output the leading space or not, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHR 16

int main (void) {
  
  int bound;
  
  puts ("Please enter the upper bound:");
  if (scanf ("%d", &bound) != 1 || bound < 1) {   /* validate input */
    fputs ("error: invalid integer argument, or bound < 1.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 1; i <= bound; i++) {  /* loop 1 - bound */
    char str[NCHR] = "";              /* array for string to print */
    int mod11 = (i - 1) % 11;         /* line break/space output check */
    
    if (i - 1) {  /* check if line break or leading space needed */
      putchar (mod11 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
    
    if (i % 3 == 0) {                 /* multiple of 3? */
      strcat (str, "Coza");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {                 /* multiple of 5? */
      strcat (str, "Loza");
    }
    if (i % 7 == 0) {                 /* multiple of 7? */
      strcat (str, "Woza");
    }
    
    if (*str) {
      fputs (str, stdout);    /* print str */
    }
    else {
      printf ("%d", i);       /* print number */
    }
  }
  
  putchar ('\n');   /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cozalozawoza
Please enter the upper bound:
110
1 2 Coza 4 Loza Coza Woza 8 Coza Loza 11
Coza 13 Woza CozaLoza 16 17 Coza 19 Loza CozaWoza 22
23 Coza Loza 26 Coza Woza 29 CozaLoza 31 32 Coza
34 LozaWoza Coza 37 38 Coza Loza 41 CozaWoza 43 44
CozaLoza 46 47 Coza Woza Loza Coza 52 53 Coza Loza
Woza Coza 58 59 CozaLoza 61 62 CozaWoza 64 Loza Coza
67 68 Coza LozaWoza 71 Coza 73 74 CozaLoza 76 Woza
Coza 79 Loza Coza 82 83 CozaWoza Loza 86 Coza 88
89 CozaLoza Woza 92 Coza 94 Loza Coza 97 Woza Coza
Loza 101 Coza 103 104 CozaLozaWoza 106 107 Coza 109 Loza
```